# Не срабатывает запрос в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку, данный код для формы связи на сайте. Работало, но потом перестало (возвращает мой же "error"), и не могу понять почему(

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if($connection == false)
{
    exit();
}

mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

if (!$connection)
{
    exit(mysqli_error());
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];

    echo ($name).'<br>';
    echo ($surname).'<br>';

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `site_orders`(`name`, `surname`) VALUES ('$name','$surname')");
    if ($result) {
        echo "Ok";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Что-то пошло не так, вернуться на <a href='/'>главную</a>";
}

?>
```

верстка

```
<form action="sender.php" method="post">
       <div class="form-col">
                    <section class="form">
                        <h3 class="section-title">Личные данные</h3>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" required name="name" value="" placeholder="" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="surname">Фамилия:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="surname" required name="surname" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="birth_date">Дата </br> рождения:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="" name="birth_date" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </section>
            <div class="wrapper-btn">
                <input type="submit" value="gogogogo">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: А что находится в `$POST` смотрели?

Comment: *возвращает мой же "error"* А надо вместо абстрактного "error" выводить возвращённое сервером сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Проверьте параметры полей таблицы `site_orders`.  Похоже, что у вас есть обязательные к заполнению поля, помимо `name` и `surname`

Comment: как вам написал @Akina, вместо *возвращает мой же "error"* выводите актуальную - `echo mysqli_error($connection);`

Comment: @Jigius , все поля в БД созданы одинаково, name поля + TEXT значение. required у инпутов я снимал, но это ничего не изменило(

Comment: UPD: @Jigius , спасибо, ваш совет помог вывести ошибку "field 'id' doesn't have a default value", это была новая колонка с типом INT

Comment: @UPD ой неприятная ошибка, исправляется 
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'. а желательно сразу настроить sql_mode в sql. Иначе после перезагрузки опять появиться ошибка

Comment: вот это if($connection == false)
{
    exit();
}
 и вот это if (!$connection)
{
    exit(mysqli_error());
}
не одно и тоже делает?

Comment: @Dmitriy , убрал ненужное по вашему совету, спасибо. А по поводу sql_mode можно подробнее, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @ВладиславВладислав ошибка "field 'id' doesn't have a default value" так лечится

Comment: Просто кто-то забыл поставить колонке авто инкрементальное значение. Никакие sql_mode править не нужно